# 5 seconds delay of Clipboard.SetText call

Tags: .net, vb6, integration, clipboard, legacy

I have simple call from legacy system, my very simple .NET win application calls

```
Clipboard.SetText("small data portion")
```

This call last 5 seconds. Next SetText calls works fine.

Most important (IMHO) piece of caller code (VB6):

```
SAAttr.nLength = Len(MySAAttr)
SAAttr.bInheritHandle = 1
SAAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = 0

CreatePipe StdOutR, StdOutW, SAAttr, 0&
SetHandleInformation StdOutR, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0&
CreatePipe StdInR, StdInW, SAAttr, 0&
SetHandleInformation StdInW, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0&

start.cb = Len(start)
start.hStdOutput = StdOutW
start.hStdError = StdOutW
start.hStdInput = StdInR
start.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES
ret = CreateProcess(0&, cmdline, 0&, 0&, 1&, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS + _    
      CREATE_NO_WINDOW, 0&, 0&, start, proc)

ret = WaitForSingleObject(proc.hProcess, pTimeout)
CloseHandle StdOutW
```

2 questions:

- What is the reason of clipboard delay?
- How to fix it (but calling process **must** be blocked - call from non blocking calls works fine)?

example code:

```
Dim start1 As DateTime = Now
Clipboard.SetText("simple data")
Dim start2 As DateTime = Now
Clipboard.SetText("simple data")
Dim start3 As DateTime = Now
Clipboard.SetText("simple data")
MessageBox.Show( (start2 - start1).ToString() & vbCrLf & _
   (start3 - start2).ToString() & vbCrLf & _
   (Now - start3).ToString() & vbCrLf )
```

Results:

00:00:05.0130000

00:00:00

00:00:00

Comment: I've recently faced very similar problem, hope somebody'll answer...

Comment: I'm guessing you are actually timing the WaitForSingleObject call delay, not the clipboard delay.  A .NET cold start can easily take 5 seconds.  Next time you run the process you get a warm start, big difference.  Only fix is a faster disk or artificially warming up the file system cache.

Comment: @HansPassant : It's not a problem with machine.

Comment: @HansPassant : It happens every time.

Comment: If these are two programs (a VB6 parent process and a .Net child process?) and the parent starts the child with anonymous pipe redirection of StdIO streams... where does the clipboard come in?  Why not use the child's StdOut to return data to the parent?  Or ignoring that for a second, what "delay" are you talking about (measured between what two events)?

Comment: @BobRiemersma : Later in caller (legacy, i'm unable to change this) code, someone read data from clipboard.
About delay: Example (edited) code should explain everything.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies things quite a bit.  It doesn't sound as if there is a VB6 issue here at all then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem for years with VB6 when using the clipboard to transfer data to Excel when Ouutlook and/or Word was running.

The problem is with Office; you need to disable the **copy multiple item** to/from clipboard to speed it up.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2817672/macro-takes-longer-than-expected-to-execute-many-individual-copy-and-p

Hope this help.